# Determine if the following set is open, closed or neither {$x\in\mathbb{R}^{2} | x_1 + x_2 = 1$} $\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

my textbook doesn't have solutions to most these problems, and this one is really giving me some trouble. Any help is appreciated.

Determine if the following set is open, closed or neither

{$x\in\mathbb{R}^{2} | x_1 + x_2 = 1$} $\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set in consideration. Define the continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ as $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. Then
$$
A=f^{-1}(\{1\})
$$
so $A$ is closed because $\{1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, any open ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ around any point $(x_1,x_2)\in A$ contains the point $(x_1+\epsilon/2,x_2)$ which is not in $A$ so $A$ is **not** open. (This follows because if $(x_1,x_2)\in A$ then $x_1+x_2=1$ and thus $(x_1+\epsilon/2)+x_2\neq 1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The set is a line. What kind of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ fit in a line?

As for being closed, what does the complement of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ look like?